# How could you dissolve a coating of CaCO3(s) from a metal plate?

Tags: solubility

> A metal plate has an unwanted coating of $\ce{CaCO3(s)}$. You must find a way to clean this metal plate without causing any scratches or abrasion. How might you dissolve the coating?

I know I should find a substance that will dissolve the coating, and then soak the plate in it. How do I determine an appropriate substance?

Comment: Acetic acid, aka vinegar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might take some time, but I would use vinegar.

The acid in vinegar is strong enough to dissolve the calcium carbonate, but it is not strong enough to dissolve metals (unless the metal reacts with water).

Comment: Do you mind explaining the chemistry behind that?

Comment: @McB I *think* it's because if a metal doesn't have a negative redox potential, it won't spontaneously oxidize (my redox chem is extremely rusty). I'm not sure what the difference between acetic acid or (what I imagine would work better) hydrochloric acid would be though.

Comment: @NickT Depending on what the metal is, hydrochloric acid could dissolve the metal (especially zinc and copper).

Comment: @LDC3 acetic acid will happily attack zinc, and HCl anecdotally won't (e.g. the "hollow penny" demo); what determines it though? More concentrated HCl might, as it would shift whatever equilibrium and thus (I think) the redox potential.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [sulfamic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfamic_acid) with formula $\ce{H3NSO3}$. The reaction is irreversible, no dangerous compound:

$$\ce{2 H3NSO3 + CaCO3 -> Ca(H2NSO3)2 + CO2 + H2O}$$